# Using chrome debugger to identify dom manipulation made by bootstrap.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

Recently I purchased a theme that is built with Bootstrap. I am trying to convert the theme to AngularJS. I noticed that the theme's look and feel of the SELECT ELEMENTS depend on bootstrap.js, since when I remove the reference to bootstrap.js the look and feel of all the select elements change back to their default state.

Here is an example of one select element in the theme:

```
 <select name="filter_bedrooms" id="inputBeds-" class="beds">
                <option value="">Beds</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
            </select>
```

I can't seem to find the code segment in bootstrap.js that is responsible for the DOM manipulation of the SELECT option, and I don't know how to do it using Chrome debugger. My end goal is to find the equivalent directive in Angular Bootstrap UI and to add it to the html code. So to be clear my question is how to use Chrome debug tools to find what JS code segment is responsible for a particular manipulation of a DOM element?

Comment: As we don't see the source, maybe the thing that styles the select is a plugin and not only bootstrap no ?

Comment: You could try right click on the element and select break on attributes modification. From chrome debugger

Comment: Thank you both. Kris, your suggestion helped me identify the code segment who is responsible for the manipulation, thank you. You can add this as an answer and I'll approve it.